Can react-native-modal-datetime-picker values be inline and display as native iOS new style inline picker?
Is it possible instead of using an extra time/date component to pop up modal date / time component to have it inline and act the same way?
Currently the only option I see is as below, where calendar time onpress sets modal to be visible. But is there a way to have this behave appear similar to native ios calendar or time selector when set to inline?



For those looking for a similar answer '@react-native-community/datetimepicker' provides a solution that works very well for inline mode.
